# Parent with multiple child and draggable height

Tags: java, android

I want to create a view which will contain multiple child view. Now I want to allow feature to drag top or bottom boundary to increase of decrease the size of child view.
Something like this :

[image: Something like this]

When user drag the bottom of colombo to top then it will decrease the size of it to minimum 1 day and increase the singapore view size.

Can someone help?

Comment: please don't just drop your assignment or "desired result" here. What code have you tried, what is(n't) working? Are the problems compile- or runtime? What error messages do you get?